# Accessible directory in Prestashop?

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In a Prestashop website, I would like to have a directory that I could access to directly, like this: website.com/directory
I've tried to add custom prestashop pages, but I really need the directory so that I can use my usual framework (Codeigniter) to build a custom-made blog for the website.
But How can I make that custom directory accessible with the link, website.com/directory?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to physically create a folder and it will be accessible, for example `prestashop-domain.com/mycustomfolder`. Then upload your framework files.

Comment: I'm shocked on how simple this was, and I was expecting Prestashop to not allow this of being so easy... Haha thank you so much